# Only one param is saving to database out of 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, parameters, nested-attributes

For some reason only one param (Status) in my update action is saving to the database once I have saved the form. My other param (Notes) only shows as a nil value no matter what I input in the form field which is strange as the logic for both of them is exactly the same.

AgentActivity model has nested attributes in the submissions model and as such I would expect it to save the attributes when I update a submission but it does not seem to be doing that.

Submission controller show method

```
  def show
    @submission.agent_activities.build
  end
```

Submission controller update method

```
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @submission.update(submission_params)
       AgentActivity.create(agent_id: current_agent.id, submission_id: @submission.id, Notes: agent_activity_params[:Notes], Status: agent_activity_params[:Status] )


       format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

Submission form

```
<%= form_for @submission do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :agent_activity do |a|%>
    <td>
      <div class="field">
        <%= select_tag(:Status, options_for_select([['In Progress', 1], ['Not Interested', 2],['Viewing Arranged', 3]])) %>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="field">
        <%= a.text_field :Notes %>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your select_tag is not using form variable (|a|) that's why you can access directly with agent_activity_params[:Status], meanwhile your notes is using field_for variable a.text_field, and you cannot access from  agent_activity_params[:Notes], if you want to do same as status you can use

```
<div class="field">
  <%= text_field_tag :Notes %>
</div>
```

Comment: Great that works thanks! Although it only lets me pass params if i remove the "require" argument in my params..is that dangerous? I still have permit though..

Comment: Yes I think you can make your code better, I just gave you shortcut to show your error